# Delphi TListView DoubleBuffered doesn't work if you are using Styles

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

When you enable application styles and set TListView's DoubleBuffered property to True, it doesn't work. When you update listitems and their subitems, it flickers. Does anyone have a solution for this?

I actually liked Styles however there are still technical issues. Now i can not trust styles.

Thanks,
K.

Comment: Have you enclosed the updates by `ListView.Items.BeginUpdate` and `ListView.Items.EndUpdate` ?

Comment: Yes i have tried that. Say I have 25 items in the list and update their subitems in every 1 sec. I use items.BeginUpdate before i change and items.EndUpdate after finish. This causes more problems. All are gone from view and comes back very fast.

Comment: You mean VCL styles? Don't use double buffered. Anywhere. It always causes problems with styles and themes. Your best approach for a list view is virtual mode.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes i mean VCL styles. Do you mean it fixes the problem if i use listview in virtual mode?

Comment: Bur even if we use virtual mode, it is going to flicker i believe. Because we will add/edit items.

Comment: With virtual mode is rendered always only the visible part of the control content, so if you'll add new item below the last visible node, no repaint will be done.

Comment: Do we need to enable OwnerData and we need to code OnData event. Am I right? If we have any changes we need to use ListView1.Refresh; to update view. Is this the best way to use Virtual Mode?

Comment: it flickers again because i use ListView1.Refresh on every change...

Comment: Don't call Refresh. You can invalidate just the items you've changed by calling `UpdateItems`. If it still flickers then submit a QC report and stop using VCL styles. They suck.

Comment: It is XE2. Well we have ordered XE3. Do you think they have fixed the problem in XE3 ?

Comment: Well, XE2 VCL styles was a bug factory. They will have fixed a lots of VCL styles bugs in XE3. No idea if it helps you.

Comment: @blacksun: This is like saying, "I put a bandaid on my skin, and then I took a bath, and it washed off".   Double buffering is a property of an underlying layer, and the VCL Styles layer is an overlaying layer.  Depending on the properties of underlying things that are being hacked, is not your problem. nor is double buffering the cure against all flicker. As David points out, you can also stop doing the things that were making it flicker, instead of saying "oh no, my bandaid's come unglued while I was in the bath".  Stupid bandaids.

Comment: After running some tests in Delphi XE3 (trial of v.17.0.4625.53395) I can say the following. With the use of 10ms update timer (extreme update rate, I know) I can say the only really *smooth* display I've seen with Windows style using double buffer (never mind if I used Windows or VCL style, virtual or non-virtual mode). So as a workaround to your problem I'd suggest you to ***implement double buffer to VCL styles*** (you can do it by overriding style hooks) ignoring the above comments saying something bad about double buffers :-)

Comment: @TLama It's true that double buffering can reduce flickering. But mostly flickering is caused by sloppy background painting. The way to fix that is to fix the real cause rather than papering over the cracks. My other gripe with double buffering is that it breaks some of the native theme effects. But I guess that's not relevant once you start using VCL styles, so let's put that to one side. And of course double buffering sucks over remote desktop/terminal server. Anyway, that's just my view. If your trials suggest that `LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER` does good things, do restore your answer.

Comment: `DoubleBuffered` does not always equal `Not Flickering`. It certainly helps reduce the flicker, but does not fix it entirely. Flickering could be a result of many other flaws.

Comment: @TLama do you mean they have fixed this in XE3? Btw, I love DoubleBuffer :) I am not sure how to use Style Hooks but i have found a website i am not sure if this is it: http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/exploring-delphi-xe2-vcl-styles-part-ii/

Comment: Btw, flicker happens only in affected subitem. If i change Subitems[1] only this subitem affected

Comment: I can't compare it with XE2, but with VCL styles each update teribly flickers in XE3 with VCL styles enabled (even in virtual mode). The only combination that looked really smooth was (as you've mentioned) Windows style with `DoubleBuffered` set to True. About the blog author, [`he's here`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/91299/rruz) and I bet he's working on it already :-)

Comment: This is an UGLY problem :) Well i also set HotTrackStyles to htHandPoint (HotTrack is false). As i move my mouse, it seems like ants on work :))

Comment: PS - A similar issue, I am using a `TMemo` control with `DoubleBuffered` enabled, and I'm not using VCL Styles, yet I still have a flicker problem. And this is a lighter-weight control than the `TListView`.

Comment: This still happens in Delphi Seattle Update 1 :)

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion at the end of this thread seems to work:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=849037

Simply remove seClient from StyleElements and manually adjust the background to the style color.